# i am getting an NoreverseMatch at / ,

Tags: python, django

I am trying to improve my models and html files for my project and while finding the solution on internet ive got this particular error.

i've tried importing render and resolvers, and also trying looking out for solution on stackoverflow but nothing works for me.

here's urls.py

```
  from django.contrib import admin
  from django.urls import path
  from accounts import views as accounts_views
  from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
  from boards import  views

  urlpatterns = [

                  path('boards/<int:pk>/topics/<topic_pk>/', 
                        views.topic_posts, name='topic_posts'),
                  path('boards.<int:pk>/topics/<topic_pk>/reply/', 
                        views.reply_topic, name='reply_topic'),
                  ]
```

here's line from base.html where its showing error

```
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
            data-target="#mainMenu" aria-controls="mainMenu" aria- 
                  expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
```

Here are my models.py file

```
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  from django.db import models
  from django.utils.text import Truncator


  class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

    def get_posts_count(self):
       return Post.objects.filter(topic__board=self).count()

    def get_last_post(self):
       return Post.objects.filter(topic__board=self).order_by('- 
            created_at').first()
```

here is html file

```
 {% for board in boards %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="{% url 'board_topics' board.pk %}">{{ board.name }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted d-block">{{ board.description }}</small>
      </td>
      <td class="align-middle">
        {{ board.get_posts_count }}
      </td>
      <td class="align-middle">
        {{ board.topics.count }}
      </td>
      <td class="align-middle">
        {% with post=board.get_last_post %}
          <small>
            <a href="{% url 'topic_posts' board.pk post.topic.pk %}">
              By {{ post.created_by.username }} at {{ post.created_at }}
            </a>
          </small>
        {% endwith %}
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

and i am getting this error

```
 "Reverse for 'topic_posts' with arguments 
  '(3, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['boards/(?P<pk>[0- 
  9]+)/topics/(?P<topic_pk>[^/]+)/$']"
```

Comment: That's because you use in your urls `views.topic_posts` but you don't have a `topic_posts` in your view.

Comment: Take care, HTML debugging is tricky when using include/extends and can conduct to misleading debug stack trace.

From what I see: you're using "somewhere" a reverse withtout the second parameters. Don't you have something like `{% url "topic_posts" some pk%}` while it should be  `{% url "topic_posts" some pk other pk%}` ?

Comment: Please post the part of html where you are calling this url `topic_posts`

Comment: @JulienKieffer this is what i've done "<a href="{% url 'topic_posts' board.pk post.topic.pk %}">" and still i am getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously your `topic_pk` is an empty string as can be seen from the error message:

```
[...] with arguments  '(2, '')' [...]
```

Comment: and also this is asking for 3 arguments and please look on my html fie which i had just uploaded

Comment: It is not asking for 3 arguments; it says that the first argument (`<pk>`) is `3`. The second argument (`<topic_pk>`) is an empty string (`''`) and that's why you are getting this error. Make sure that your `post.topic.pk` exists.